# How to extrude inside mesh while keeping relative proportions from edges

Tags: edges, extrude

I can select the mesh letter I, extrude it on the X axis and scale it inward to create an edge around it.

When I do the same process with the mesh letter O, the result is this:
[image: O and I extruded]

I would like to be able to create an identical inward edge that is inside the larger object, not only on the letter O but on any other mesh object.

How can I do this?

And how can I get rid of the face behind the newly extruded edge?

EDIT: I tried insetting but the mesh letter O looks like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried ALT + S?

Comment: Looks like you want insetting rather than extruding. Try undoing extrusion and running `I` to inset. Also seems that scale for the object on the right isn't applied (Object mode > Ctrl+A)

Comment: Tried insert, but the result is imperfect due to how the faces are generate - https://imgur.com/a/pxfu2

Comment: What there is such unusual in how "faces are generated" for that mesh? Inset works incorrect when transforms aren't applied, did you check if they are? Is the O object (one on the left) just a circle extruded inwards? If not then show its wireframe (object in Edit mode, Wireframe shading) and in Solid mode, perspective view. Or upload it https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and share

Comment: Added the test file to the question. If you look at the O in the top right corner you will see what I mean. Want the inside to be a perfect O as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select all internal Edges and delete them.

   [image: 1]
2. Select whats left (two circles should left) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> and choose **Bridge Edge Loops**.

   [image: 2]
3. Press <kbd>I</kbd> and **Inset** is working fine also you will have neat topology.

   [image: 3]

Comment: Thank you! Is there an easier way to select the inside edges besides selecting everything but the edges, then select inverse? Could be an issue with larger meshes.

Comment: Or a way to convert a vector to a mesh in such a way that this process is not needed?

Comment: I was using "C" for Circle Select. You can also select outward edges and invert them or try to select one from the inside and Shift + G to Select Similar.

Comment: @MarekAndreansky Sadly no, only manual retopology will give you nice results. Unfortunately converting from Text to Mesh is pretty messy.

Comment: Yes, tried converting a few vectors and had to fix most of them manually. Either way, thank you very much Luke!!